# PHP Socket doesn't working on Server

Tags: php, websocket

I have a domain (ad-box.deslab.vn). I want to PHP socket to communicate with clients. However, After I run program, it has error:

****Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [22]: Invalid argument in /home/vietchip/public_html/deslab.vn/ad-box/index.php on line 27
socket_bind() failed: reason: Invalid argument socket_bind() failed: reason: Invalid argument****

Link: ad-box.deslab.vn/index.php

Code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* Allow the script to hang around waiting for connections. */
set_time_limit(0);

/* Turn on implicit output flushing so we see what we're getting
* as it comes in. */
ob_implicit_flush();

$address = "181.224.157.142";
$port = 10000;

// Create Socket
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if ($sock === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}
if (!socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)) { 
    echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)); 
 exit; 
}

// Bind socket to port
socket_bind($sock, $address, $port);
if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
    echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

// Start listening for connection
socket_listen($sock, 5);   // Maximum is 5 connection
if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) {
    echo "socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

// Handling connection from client
do {
    $msgsock = socket_accept($sock); // msgsock is a client connect to webserver
    if ($msgsock === false) {
        echo "socket_accept() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
        break;
    }

    $request ="PHP said : you are sent " . socket_read($msgsock, 2048, PHP_BINARY_READ);
    socket_write($msgsock, $request, strlen($request));
    socket_close($msgsock);  // Close connect of client
} while (true);
socket_close($sock);  // Close socket of server
```

?>

Please help me fix it.
Thanks.

Comment: Show uw your code. Don't link to it. Put it in your question.

Comment: I have inserted my code in my question. Please help me find solution? Thanks